# override existing account page with custom visualforce page

Tags: apex

Hi all i am new to salesforce please help me out from this,
I have VF page to override standard Account "new" button page, In that VF page i have Parent Account field which will get the Lookup to Account Record and another problem is i am not able to retrive billing and shipping address fields , I'm facing problem and can't able to resolve it.Please help me out from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override a Visualforce by navigating to:

Setup > Customize > Accounts > Buttons, Links, and Actions > then find a row have label named "New".

Click "Edit" there to set the Visualforce page.

For other custom action you can use "[Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm)" for finding parent account or other details.

[image]

---

Field may not be visible due to FLS permission:

Perhaps you don't have filed level permission for those fields.

Go to Setup > Manage User > Profile | Select the profile and check for Field Level Security permission for the "Account Object.

---

Address type fields need to be will need to reference them individually. Like: BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingState, BillingStreet etc.

Example: `<apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}"></apex:inputfield>`

Comment: and also i am not able to access billing address and shipping address..
means that Billing Street  , Billing City  , Billing State/Province Billing Zip/Postal Code ,Billing Country and same for shipping also

Comment: @aryan Aren't those fields not visible on page or something else?

Comment: ya those fields are not visible on page

Comment: Perhaps you don't have filed level permission for those fields. Go to Setup > Manage User > Profile | Select the profile and check for Field Level Security permission for the "Account Object. @aryan

Comment: ok that is cool ...but what about parent account field ...should i need to build a custom lookup for that ???

Comment: @aryan you can put `<apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ParentID}"></apex:inputfield>` to provide parent lookup.

Comment: wow!! thanx sir it's working !!!! but i have 1 more problem which is i m not able to access Billing Street , Billing City , Billing State/Province Billing Zip/Postal Code ,Billing Country  fields and also fields of shipping addresss ..i also check field level security..

Comment: there is only two fileds billing address and shipping address and on page side there is 5 -5 filed for each Billing Street , Billing City , Billing State/Province Billing Zip/Postal Code ,Billing Country fields and  Shipping Street , Shipping City , Shipping State/Province Shipping Zip/Postal Code ,Shipping Country fields

Comment: @aryan They are not visible because your are not showing then on page. There is no input field referencing these fields on page. This block is empty `<apex:pageblocksection id="AddressInformationPBS" title="Address Information">
            </apex:pageblocksection>
`

Comment: ya i am not showing that because ..it is giving me error that data type address is not supported

Comment: @aryan You will need to reference them individually. Like:  BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingState, BillingStreet etc. Example: `<apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}"></apex:inputfield>`

Comment: wow!!!!!!!! Thanx a lot sir !!!!
as i am new on salesforce ...i want to learn all string methods and i am working
on this by following this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm
but what i need is can you provide me some task related to the same ?

Comment: ya sure sir i will mark it as a best answer !!!

Comment: Sir 1 more problem i have ...if u see on standard  page of account in address information block there is a command link (copy Billing Address to Shipping Address ) so sir can u help me out from this that how can i achieve this functionality